# Should the main navigation transition run faster?

Tags: discussion, design, links

The main navigation transition looks like slow motion.

When I hover over a link on the main navigation it feels like the background transition effect takes ages, this behaviour is disturbing me, like when I'm being chased on a dream and I can barely move my legs.

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, voting is different on meta sites. Downvotes just mean that people disagree with your proposal

Comment: +1. very useful infromation

Answer (score 1):

It's fine for me (tested on a new mac and on old-ish pc) in Chrome, Safari. Firefox and Internet explorer.

Try switching to a more modern browser, with a faster JavaScript engine.

Failing that, it might just be that your computer is too out if date for modern browser animations.

If its not your browser, and you just don't personally like the speed of the transition, you'll need to provide some sort of evidence that the current speed is detrimental to the site.

Going off past experience the developers won't make tiny changes like that unless they're provided with compelling evidence to show why it's necessary.

Comment: Not a browser issue I'm on Ubuntu and I tested in FireFox 18 and in Chromium 23.0.1271.97

Comment: If it's just personal taste then I don't think it will be changed. If it bothers you enough just add a userscript to override the transition. The current CSS rule is `.nav a:hover { -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in; }`. It would be trivial to speed that up for your own preferences